# Change content of a view depending on iframe size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe

My Rails app has a page that can be displayed in an iframe of a third-party website. I would like to change the content of my page based on iframe size. (For example, display only 1 element instead of 3, if the iframe size is small).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to take a look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

The basic idea is something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .hide_on_small_screens { display: none; }
}
```

You can then add this or similar classes to the objects you want to hide/show. Alternatively you can just write the code for say a class like `.iframe_wrapper`